Extracting a pattern in Informatica
My input looks like
FIELD1 = 10000000,00, ,,00,Q,,00, ,,00,X,,00,2,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,00,Q,,
My single Demiliter is (, ,,)and i can have (,Q,,).
I need to just extract either ( ) in case of (, ,,) or (Q) in case of (,Q,,)
how can i do it?
Tried Reg_Extract:
REG_EXTRACT(FIELD1,'(.)(,[Q, ],,)(.)',2,2) --> still returns , ,,
I tried REG_EXTRACT(FIELD1,'(.)(,[Q, ],,)(.)',2,2) --> still returns , ,,
Expecting Q.
In case of ,Q,, I need Q
In case of , ,, I need just space
